# Display summary of paragraph text field in twig

Tags: theming, paragraphs

I have a paragraph type called News. In this paragraph type I have a text field (field_news_intro ) with a summary. How do I display the summary in a twig template?

`content.field_news_intro.summary` seemed logical, but it doesn't return anything.

My template is called paragraph--news.html.twig

```
<div class="copy larger">
  {{ content.field_news_intro.summary }}
</div>
<div class="copy">
  {{ content.field_news_intro }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. One of the answers did help. {{ content.field_description['#items'][0].summary }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the summary with `summary` attribute in field level.

```
{{ content.YOUR_FIELD_NAME['#items'][0].summary }}
```

in your case answer will be :

```
{{ content.field_description['#items'][0].summary }}
```